# Tree diagram for Full House in Poker

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, poker

So I wanted to follow up on question I asked yesterday (that was well answered), but I wanted to look at it in a more visual way.

I was asking how many ways there are to make a full house in Poker without using the combinations method. I was well explained the formula :

\begin{equation}\frac{52\times3\times2\times48\times3}{3!2!}=3744\end{equation}

But now if I try to explore the different ways with a diagram such as the one below, would there be a way to make a calculation out of it?

My reasoning could be wrong, but I believe we could start by picking any card (let's call it A), followed by any other (which will be A or a different one B). If that second card is A, I could still choose any of the 50 remaining cards (looking for a third A or any new value). However if that second card is B, the possibilities now drop to 6 because I could then only choose one of the three remaining A or B.

I don't know if my diagram is right or makes sense, but with a similar approach is it possible to make a calculation to obtain the answer 3744?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you could use a tree diagram if you so wished.  No, your tree diagram is not quite correct.  In particular, moving from the first position to the second, this should also have been a branching point... $3$ in the one direction, $48$ in the other direction.

Comment: That said... why you would insist on using a tree diagram like this for this problem is beyond me.  It seems like far too much arithmetic and unnecessary tedium in terms of organizing the needed information.  The combinations approach is far superior.

Comment: Extending JMoravitz' last comment, the *nice* thing about a full house is that it precisely uses all 5 cards as a pair + a triplet.  There are $(13 \times 12)$ ways of choosing the ranks of the pair and triplet.  Assuming that the full house is 3 Aces and 2 Kings, there are then $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of choosing which 3 Aces will be included and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing which 2 Kings will be included.  So final answer **must be** $$(13 \times 12) \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{4}{2}.$$

Comment: To clarify, that calculation by @user2661923 is for the unordered hands.  For ordered hands, multiply that result by $5!$

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I understand the methods you have mentionned and I'm certainly not looking to use a tree diagram instead because I know it's a lot more complicated. I was just trying to visualize this specific problem with a diagram an see how a calculation would work... I'm fairly new to this type of mathematics and I understand this is not the "proper" way to solve this problem, but I wanted to explore this example with more of a visual approach.